# How To Specify Width & Height Of The Image Thumbnail In Facebook Like Box

Tags: facebook

I'm working on website pagespeed, and GTMetrix says:
The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes.

This is for the image thumbnail in Facebook Like box.. I want to add for the width 50px and height 50px for the thumbnails.

Comment: What is your current markup/code? Could you add it in? *(you can take out the facebook link)*

Comment: I used the iframe version for the facebook like box.

Comment: The only attributes I know to add is the width and height for the box... but my problem is that I want to add width and height of the profile picture for facebook likes.

Comment: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/273703_100007670139143_880405386_q.jpg (Dimensions: 50 x 50)

Comment: You can not modify the HTML code the Like Box displays.